# Estimation for a animation game app

Tags: language-agnostic

HI All,

I am new to the world of Animation in iPhone, I have a team which has experience of developing CMS apps with little bit of animation in it. I would would like to develop an application like...

[link text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwHETnBT1Tw)

I have limitations to put another hyperlink over here but you can search with "Alex Bop Bag" in youtube for other video.

It would be a great help if anybody can suggest how much time i much time it would take for a person who is new to animation world but good in iPhone development.

your feedback would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard the phrase "How long is a piece of string?" before?

There's really so many factors here, how many developers, how well they work as a team, experience and skill levels, project complexity, possible issues/time sinks, project management skills, etc.

It's so dynamic, unless you have an idea from previous attempts at tasks with similar complexity it's very hard to say.

So I guess the answer is the standard "It depends". I would suggest trying something small to get an idea for how well your team performs and to get an idea of what to expect with a more complex project.

Comment: HI Timothy,

First of all thanks for your reply, you are right and i also know that it depends on the things you have mentioned. What you said is generic one and i think most of people in development know this things and take care of it. 

I am looking for tips from a persons having experience in such application development. 

Even it would be good if he can tell me that what should be the time line for a(single) person having good experience in iPhone Animation and graphics development and has developed few simple game applications.

Thanks.